# Converting a list of tuples into a list of strings

Tags: python

So I have a list of tuples, for example `[('GGG',), ('AAA',), ('BBB',)]` and I want to convert it into a list of strings: `['GGG' , 'AAA', 'BBB']`.

I have tried using a for loop with the join method but cannot get it to work. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: are the elements in the list of tuples ` [(GGG,), (AAA,), (BBB,)]` also strings?

Comment: yeah they are, that's my mistake. I'll update the question.

Comment: just use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: Surprised no one mentioned: `[x[0] for x in items]`

Comment: I think @mentalita covered that, more or less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list_of_tuples = [('GGG',), ('AAA',), ('BBB',)]
>>> my_list_of_strings = [str(*x) for x in my_list_of_tuples]
>>> my_list_of_strings
['GGG', 'AAA', 'BBB']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

e.g.

```
from itertools import chain
x = [('GGG',), ('AAA',), ('BBB',)]
print(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

output

> ['GGG', 'AAA', 'BBB']

The use of `list` is only to allow printing the output. It forces the lazy object returned from `chain.from_iterable` to be evaluated immediately. You don't need it if you will later iterate over object.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. If array is `z = [('GGG',), ('AAA',), ('BBB',)]`, then:

1) Using `zip`: `list(list(zip(*z))[0])`

well the other ways have been just written by the other two most recent answers :).

Also, even though it was not asked, but I got interested in performance, and I wanted to share the results of a rather simple benchmark:

Input

```
z = [('aaa',) for i in range(10000)]
```

@Paul Rooney

```
%timeit itertools.chain.from_iterable(z)
# 129 ns ± 2.52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

@COLDSPEED

```
%timeit [x[0] for x in z]
# 254 µs ± 1.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@this

```
%timeit list(zip(*z))[0]
# 272 µs ± 794 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@mentalita

```
%timeit [str(*x) for x in z]
# 809 µs ± 904 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t=[('GGG',), ('AAA',), ('BBB',)]
str=[]
for each in t:
    str.append(each[0])
print str
```

Above one gives list of strings

Comment: `str` is a bad variable name. There is an inbuilt function called that.

Comment: Hope he need simple logic for his task. Any way next time I will take care of variable names also.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `itertools` `chain` method tested in `python2` & `python3`

```
from itertools import chain
data = [('GGG',), ('AAA',), ('BBB',)]
for item in itertools.chain(*data):
    print(item)
```

> The itertools.chain method returns `chain` object, you can get
>   elements using `list` or `iterate` using `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'isinstance`' or `type()==tuple` method can done the job in just one line using list comprehension :

```
 print([j for i in your_list for j in i if isinstance(i,tuple)])
```

:)